# How to make a circular image in css

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to this sort of thing but this is my issue.
I've looked through a couple of questions and it makes sense with how to make it circular but the image which is made circular is half cut off, is there a way of fixing this.
I am using HTML and CSS.

```
circular_image {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 125px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: use `border-radius:50%`

Comment: Could you show a picture?

Comment: Thanks you all for your help and fast responses :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your css rule needs a `.` (*if it applied with a `class`*) or `#` (*if it is applied with an `id`*) at the start.

Also if you apply the rule to a container of the image you need to set the image to re-size accordingly to fit the circle;

Finally, `50%` radius is all you need for a circle.

```css
.circular_image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  /* commented for demo
  float: left;
  margin-left: 125px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  */
  
  /*for demo*/
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.circular_image img{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
with container

<div class="circular_image">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500"/>
</div>

<br><br>
directly on image

<img class="circular_image" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/500"/>
```

Comment: This only works if the image is square. Replace your image with a rectangle one and it doesnt work.

Comment: @johnw182, yes. The OP was about a square image, and hence this answer.

Answer (score 51):

This work for me

```
clip-path: circle();
```

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the answer... Worked super well. I had to use this solution when Boostrap's "roundedCircle" prop wasn't working for me in React.js.

Comment: Thanks, this works so much better than border-radius: 50%, when the image doesn't have the same width and height

Comment: clip-path has limited browser support with most all browsers. Make sure the limitations are something you can deal with. https://caniuse.com/css-clip-path

Comment: johnw182, reading your comment and looking at the link you gave might give the impression that this is only partially supported by browsers. But a closer reading of the link seems to indicate that most if not all the major browsers support the answers as given, and any limitations are to other formulations (e.g. external SVG clip paths) not relevant to this answer.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the border-radius to the img itself, not to the containing div. As you know images are square or rectangular and putting them inside something circle will of course cut off the boundaries.

```
img { 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/LLo1u3Ld/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/LLo1u3Ld/1/)

Answer (score 5):

Just add the `border-radius:50%;` to `circular_image`Class.

Below the neet code is....

```
.circular_image{
    float:left;
    margin-left:125px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%; /* Modified*/
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
    background-color: blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer to use the `clip-path: circle();` does the magic. Just set a width or a height to the container that holds the image and apply the `clip-path: circle()` property to the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

if you use tailwincss you can opt-in this

```
<Image
 className="h-[50px] w-[50px] rounded-full object-cover"
 src={HouseImage}
 alt="house to invest in"
/>
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

clip-path:circle();
works for me in any senerio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).