# How to make a circular image?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image: navbar]

The problem is this image, I want to make it circular, I used border-radius:50% and set equal height and width. I searched for the question and found this one [How to make a circular image in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700841/how-to-make-a-circular-image-in-css) and I tried to make something similar but I used flexbox.

```js
<div className='nav-bar'>
            <ul className='nav-links'>
                <li className='nav-link'>
                    <Link >
                        Home
                    </Link>
                </li>

                <li className='nav-link'>
                    <Link >
                        Add question
                    </Link>
                </li>

                <li className='nav-link'>
                    <Link >
                        Leaderboard
                    </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>

                <ul className='nav-user-sign-out'>
                    <li className='nav-item'>
                        <p>Welcome, </p>
                    </li>

                    <li className='nav-item'>
                        <div className='avatar'>
                            <img src={} alt='' />
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li className='nav-item'>
                        <button className='sign-out'>
                            Sign out
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>;
```

```css
.nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
}

Link {
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav-user-sign-out {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.sign-out {
    padding: 10px;
}

.avatar {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Where are you coming up with the `<Link>` element and usage like that? It's invalid standard HTML Note, also, that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob I'm using <Link> element because this isn't HTML, it's jsx.

Answer (score 0):

Either make height and width of fixed and equal value or if you are using percentage confirm to that image has same width and height.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a `codesandbox` with your code, and it's working without an issue, maybe the issue is with another CSS class that declared somewhere else, or maybe the `object-fit` property on the image. I'll put the link to my sandbox here, feel free to go ahead and try it with your code. I added `object-fit` to the image styles there.

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-water-dz63x?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
}

Link {
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav-user-sign-out {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.sign-out {
    padding: 10px;
}

.avatar {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 105px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div className='nav-bar'>
            <ul className='nav-links'>
                <li className='nav-link'>
                    <Link >
                        Home
                    </Link>
                </li>

                <li className='nav-link'>
                    <Link >
                        Add question
                    </Link>
                </li>

                <li className='nav-link'>
                    <Link >
                        Leaderboard
                    </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>

                <ul className='nav-user-sign-out'>
                    <li className='nav-item'>
                        <p>Welcome, </p>
                    </li>

                    <li className='nav-item'>
                        <div className='avatar'>
                            <img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2015/02/Facebook_Embed.png" alt=''width ="200" />
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li className='nav-item'>
                        <button className='sign-out'>
                            Sign out
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
```